# How to use parameters using parameter file in Informatica Cloud?

Tags: cloud, etl, data-migration, informatica

Can Any one tell me how to do parameterization using file in Informatica Cloud?

I've created a parameter and assigned it in filter and configured the parameter file under userparameters folder.. But while executing the mapping configuration task.. i'm facing the below error:

```
TE_7002 Transformation stopped due to a fatal error in the mapping. The expression [SalesAmount=$$salesamt] contains the following errors [<<PM Parse Error>> [=]: function cannot resolve operands of ambiguously mismatching types. ... SalesAmount=>>>>$$salesamt<<<<].
```

The content of my parameter file is

```
    [Global]
$$salesamt=2500
```

Pls let me know, the correct way to use parameter file in Informatica Cloud, if the above one is wrong.

Comment: The error message says that the datatypes don't match. How is the parameter declared? [If at all it is - I'm not sure how parameter declaration works in Infa Cloud now...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the Global in Informatica cloud par file.Just mention the parameter value in the parameter file.

$$salesamt=2500